Is it fair to use the possessive as misdirection for a plural definition?
In a fair cryptic crossword clue the definition part must match the solution in tense and pluralisation.
Is it generally considered fair to use the possessive, 's, as misdirection for a plural definition?
After all said out loud monk's and monks sound the same. But perhaps the plural possessive monks' is required to be fair in my example below (the solution is plural).

Monk's tea stolen from lady's hands (7)

Solution with explanation spoilered...

 The definition: Monk's. The wordplay: HER (lady's) MITTS (hands) MITS (tea stolen), gives the answer HERMITS.


Is it possible the setter is just cluing rot13(urezvg'f) here, but omitting the punctuation from the grid? (In the same way that "Baba O'Riley" would be entered as BABAORILEY...) The fact that punctuation is usually omitted in the grid when entering answers makes that way seem legit to me...

I would think that unfair for a couple reasons.  First, a "hermit" is not a synonym for a "monk".  Second, and to your point, Monk is singular so if the answer is meant to be a synonym, it should also be singular.  Ignoring my complaint about the definition, I'd say the clue could work for "hermit".  Though to do so, you'd be reading "monk's" as a contraction of "monk is".

I'm with @Stiv here - you could interpret it so the clue is cluing the possesessive form of the answer, rather than the plural. I might object to it on grounds of "I don't want a random noun with 's after it as an entry in a grid", then, but the clue wouldn't inherently be wrong if you took that interpretation.
